# How to remove certain characters from a list?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list

`List = ['1a', 'Gb', '3c', 'Gd']`

Is there a way to remove the second character of each character pair in the list?

Thus producing...

`['1', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: What have you already tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: If you cut off the second character, you won't get `['1', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: Did you mean to say "remove the first character in the list", like your result mostly shows, or did you give the wrong result?

Comment: @user2387370 Maybe your desired result doesn't match your question?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
[item[0] for item in List]
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a new list:

```
new_list = [item[0] for item in old_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
array = ['1a', 'Gb', '3c', 'Gd']
new_array = []

for item in array:
    new_array.append(item[:1])

print new_array
```

Comment: It works but it is a pretty inefficient and non-pythonic way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the second character in the list, as "Is there a way to remove the second character of each character pair in the list?" suggests:

```
test = ['1a', 'Gb', '3c', 'Gd']
new = [i[:1] for i in test]
```

However, the majority of your sample result suggests you want to remove the first character:

```
new = [i[1:], for i in  test]
```

However, as it says in the comments to your question, your example result - `['1', 'b', 'c', 'd']` - is neither of these things. Please edit your question to make it clear what you want.